# How do I save data on a server ("In the cloud")?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am learning web application development. To save anything on a server, ("In the cloud," like Facebook and Google do) within a web application, do I need to use server side code, or can it be accomplished another way?

Comment: "In the cloud" is just a marketing term, it is just like any other server.

Comment: @Lime How do you save data from the client on any other server?

Comment: First you put up a progress bar.  In my experience, cloud computing is painfully slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web application typically saves data in a (SQL) database. You could start off with a DB software (mysql, postgres, etc.) running on the same server as your application. As you application scales, you can evaluate other options such as separating out the work load, memcache, etc.

Comment: So to clarify, I need server-side code to save data on a server?

Comment: Yes, your web application would be a PHP / Perl / Python / script.